# Filtering json in javascript/typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8, angular9

I have a json which as follows.

```
const d = {
data:{name:"name1", type:"abc"},
parent:{
    data: {name:"parent1"},
    parent:{
      data: { name:"superparent1"},
      parent: null
     }  
  }
}
```

I want to get final output as "superparent1 / parent1 / name1" in an array. It should show the parent till the parent is null. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you show the example of the output, cause I do not get what do you mean?

Comment: Do you want to print a string `superparent1 / parent1 / name1` from null parent to outermost object's name?

Comment: @RohitKhandelwal in a array as this is just a example. At run time data may be huge

Comment: I voted to close this until you can clarify the exact input and the expected output.

Comment: Please don;t close. It is simple question I have a json and what I want as output is also mentioned. You can see Rohit comment he understood correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const d = {
  data: {
    name: "name1",
    type: "abc"
  },
  parent: {
    data: {
      name: "parent1"
    },
    parent: {
      data: {
        name: "superparent1"
      },
      parent: null
    }
  }
}
const d1 = {
  data: {
    name: "name1",
    type: "abc"
  },
  parent: {
    data: {
      name: "parent1"
    },
    parent: {
      data: {
        name: "superparent1"
      },
      parent: null
    }
  }
}

const resArr = [];

const formatFunc = (obj, arr) => {
  if (obj) {
    arr.push(obj.data.name);
    return formatFunc(obj.parent, arr);
  } else {
    return "end";
  }
}

const formatArrObj = (arr) => {
  let iArr = [];
  arr.map(item => {
    formatFunc(item, iArr);
    const str = iArr.reverse().join("/");
    resArr.push(str);
    iArr = [];
  })
}

formatArrObj([d, d1]);

console.log(resArr);
```

This is what you were looking for or not?

Comment: [superparent1 / parent1 / name1] something like this

Comment: I have edited the answer, now it will output what you required. @RAZZZ

Comment: Just a question in your solution. suppose with d I have d1(means instead of d, if I have a array containing d and d1(arr[d,d1])) in an array [uperparent1 / parent1 / name1, uperparent2 / parent2 / name2]] and so on how can I do that?

Comment: how can I get comma separated output as I mentioned in above comment

Comment: hey Rohit is it possible for you to update your answer?

Comment: Yes, I can it's very simple.

Comment: hey @RAZZZ I have updated my answer, you can check

Comment: how can I pass more data. using for each?

Comment: In `formatArrObj` you have to provide an array of objects as an argument, further, the function will iterate and solve your problem automatically. If you want to modify elements in the middle before formatting, you can do that inside the `map` function.

Answer (score 0):

Using a recursive method you can do something like this:

```js
const filter = (a) => {
    if(a.parent == null) {
      return [a.data.name];
    } else {
      return [...filter(a.parent), a.data.name];
  }
}
```

You can add appropriate typescript types where necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need some code like this:

```
const output = [];
const getParent = (obj) => {
    output.push(obj.data.name)

    if (!obj.parent) {
        return 
    }

    return getParent(obj.parent)
}
getParent(d);
const formattedOutput = output.reverse().join(' / ');
```

Comment: Just a question in your solution. suppose with d I have d1(means instead of d, if I have a array containing d and d1(arr[d,d1])) in an array [uperparent1 / parent1 / name1, uperparent2 / parent2 / name2]] and so on how can I do that?how can I get comma separated output as I mentioned in above comment

Comment: You can create another array, let suppose const finalOut = [], and then use [d0, d1, d2].forEach(d => { const output = []; ...my code... getParent(d); finalOut.push(formattedOutput) } )

Comment: could you please add your code above instead of comment?

Comment: I tried your code and it is giving wrong output. for first element is giving correct output [superparent1 / parent1 / name1]  but for second element [uperparent2 / parent2 / name2/superparent1 / parent1 / name1]  and for third element even more wrong